# LARAVEL with AJAX , modified route

Tags: jquery, ajax, laravel

I am beginning with Laravel and Ajax and of course I have a problem :-(

Here a script which is running fine

```
$.ajax({
        type : 'GET', 
        url : 'getListeGenreCategorieAjax/'+$(this).val() , 
        dataType : 'html',
        beforeSend : function() {$('#waiting').show(); }, // faire apparaitre l'image d'attente
        success : function(data){ 
                                    $('#id_genre').html(data); // affichage des résultats dans le select
                                    $("#id_genre option[value='"+id_genre_cache+"']").attr("selected", true);
                                    $('#waiting').hide();
                                }
        });
```

When I run it, I see the route in firebug :

```
http://localhost/predami_new/public/getListeGenreCategorieAjax/VIDEO
```

Perfect ! I receive a response, all is running fine.

Now I do the same thing on another page and it does not work anymore. The route is see is now :

```
http://localhost/predami_new/public/formulaire_produit/getListeGenreCategorieAjax/VIDEO
```

It does not work because there is this **"formulaire_produit/"** which has been inserted into the route.

My question : why this route is modify on another page ? What must I do ?

thanks a lot for your feedback. And have a nice day.

Dominique

Comment: Please mark the answer that has helped you as accepted instead of changing the title of your question to solved

Answer (score 2):

It is due to you use relative url in the `url` parameter. When you are at the page `http://localhost/predami_new/public/` it appends `'getListeGenreCategorieAjax/'+$(this).val()` and when you are at the page `http://localhost/predami_new/public/formulaire_produit/` it also appends the same. You should use absolute url instead:

```
url : '{{URL::to('/')}}/getListeGenreCategorieAjax/'+$(this).val()
```

Or if your ajax code is not in the blade file:

```
url : '/predami_new/public/getListeGenreCategorieAjax/'+$(this).val()
```

Comment: Thanks for the answer, but I have a doubt. Because I understand I must make some "php code" into a javascript file. I tried of course but it does not work. I have now a route like that : http://localhost/predami_new/public/NaNVIDEO. See there is NAN error now. But I have understood the pb , I will find a wrokaround like an hidden field somewhere with this url. Thanks.

Comment: Great ! it works fine now with an hidden field + the tip of user3714582. Thanks.